# Local database without sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am creating a C# application that I will install on some low end pcs. All I can install on low end machines is .NET framework. I want to use some sort of database so that I can store information that application will be scraping from internet. Can anyone suggest me how to proceed about that ? I cant install any version of sql server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best option is to use an access database. You won't need to install anything on the machine it is virtually like using a flat file that can be queried like a database :)

Comment: I think I would go with your solution for the time being.

Comment: is MS Access still an option in year 2022? ;)

Answer (score 11):

SQLite seems to be the answer. http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: SQLLite is a simple and quick (albeit not fast) solution. You can use a lot of management consoles to manage it, even some handy Firefox extensions, I use SQLLite manager: https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/5817/

Comment: Can I deploy with application itself ? I mean application starts and deploy sqllite if not already present ?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [SqlServerCe](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx) 3.5, it's compatible with EF 4.0 and it's so easy to deploy, just 2 .dll files.

Comment: By using SQL CE you would also be in a position where you can easily upgrade to a SQL Server implementation if you wanted.

Comment: Actually, my requirement does not require upgrading to SQL server at anytime but thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 4):

VistaDB, SQLite, Compact Edition of SQL Server, MS Access, Firebird... the options are many and a list of them can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

There is a C# wrapper [here](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki).

Comment: The wrapper link is not working anymore. Can you relink it maybe?